# WARNING:tensorflow:11 out of the last 11 calls to triggered tf.function retracing

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, warnings

Anyone know the reason for this error?

```
WARNING:tensorflow:No training configuration found in the save file, so the model was *not* compiled. Compile it manually.
WARNING:tensorflow:11 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x000001F9D1C05EE0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
WARNING:tensorflow:11 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x000001F9D5604670> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\_kmeans.py:973: FutureWarning: 'n_jobs' was deprecated in version 0.23 and will be removed in 0.25.
  warnings.warn("'n_jobs' was deprecated in version 0.23 and will be"
```

Answer (score 22):

**{TLDR}** try replacing **model.predict(x)** by **model(x)**

### My Solution

I also had issues with the warning:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:11 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function.<locals>.predict_function at 0x000001F9D1C05EE0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.
```

I was able to solve it with replacing **model.predict(x)** by directly using **model(x)**

---

#### Background Infos where I encountered the problem

I am predicting time series and fit the last layer of my model every new sampling time to the latest data. Therefore I

1. generate and fit a base model and freeze all layers + put a top layer
2. fit to new data and **predict inside a loop**

I tried to implement a custom predict function with a signature as suggested from the Warning and @TFer2. This however yielded the error

```
RuntimeError: Detected a call to `Model.predict` inside a `tf.function`. `Model.predict is a high-level endpoint that manages its own `tf.function`. Please move the call to `Model.predict` outside of all enclosing `tf.function`s. Note that you can call a `Model` directly on `Tensor`s inside a `tf.function` like: `model(x)`.
```

With this error I was then able to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Replacing model.predict(x) by directly using model(x) worked for me

Comment: Though interestingly, I still get the WARNING, but the execution speed increased tenfold

Comment: Remember to do `model(x, training=False)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you call a function with the same argument type tensorflow will reuse a previously traced graph else will create new graph.

A function determines, whether to reuse  a traced concrete function by computing a `cache key from an input's args and kwargs`:

- A key generated for a `tf.Tensor` argument is its `shape` and `type` (*input signatures*)
- The key generated  for a `tf.Variable` argument is its `id()`.
- A key generated for a `python` primitive is its `value`.
- The key generated for nested `dicts, lists, tuples, namedtuples`, and `attrs` is the `flattened tuple`.

Retracing ensures that tensorflow generates correct graphs for each set of inputs.  But it is expensive.

You have to avoid execessive retracing else tensorflow will usually issue a warning as above.

There are few ways that you can control tracing behavior:

- Specify an `input_signature in tf.function`
- specify a `[None] dimension in tf.TensorSpec` to allow for flexibility in trace reuse
- `Cast python arguments to Tensors` to reduce retracing

For more details you can refer [Better performance with tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#python_or_tensor_args).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me and I was able to get rid of most of the tf warnings including this:

```
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(0)
```

If that doesn't work, perhaps the logging module could be of help here:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```